# creating WindsorContainer results in type conversion error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to following book : [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework by Steven Sanderson](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430210078)...

The line  `container = new WindsorContainer(xi);` produces this error:

> Could not convert from 'DomainModel.Abstract.IPeopleRepository, DomainModel' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found**

```
public WindsorControllerFactory()
{
    ConfigResource confres = new ConfigResource("castle");

    XmlInterpreter xi = new XmlInterpreter(confres);

    container = new WindsorContainer(xi);

    // Also register all the controller types as transient
    var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                          where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                          select t;

    foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
    {
        container.AddComponentLifeStyle(t.FullName, t, LifestyleType.Transient);
    }
}
```

The castle config:

```
  <castle>
    <components>
      <component id="PeopleRepository"
                 service="DomainModel.Abstract.IPeopleRepository, DomainModel"
                 type="DomainModel.Concrete.FakePeopleRepository, DomainModel" 
                 >
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Where is your "container" variable declared?  Try changing "container = new WindsorContainer(xi);"  to "var container = new WindsorContainer(xi);"

Comment: I edited the question to show how I declared "container" variable.

Comment: FYI, your `GetControllerInstance` method should return the following on a null `controllerType` - `return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);`. This will properly throw a 404 error if the controller cannot be found.

Comment: @p.campbell - I think your edit may have removed a little too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanderson's book is outdated about the MVC-Windsor integration. Don't code your own (or the book's) controller factory. Use [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)'s Windsor integration instead.

Also, registering controllers within the controller factory is plain bad practice. The controller factory is there to instantiate controllers, not to manage container registrations.

UPDATE: MvcContrib for ASP.NET MVC 3 removed all controller factories and deprecated all IoC integrations.

Comment: Where _is_ the ControllerFactory in MVCcontrib? I've even downloaded the extras library and I can't find it.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question around why it's throwing that error though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd lose the empty `PeopleController` constructor