# MVC - Creating a Castle Windsor Controller Factory - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am introducing DI into my MS MVC application and I am having trouble getting the controllers instantiated from within my custom Controller Factory. It seems that the overridden  "GetControllerInstance" is not being called.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

My Controller Factory:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public WindsorControllerFactory()
    {
        var controllerTypes = from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                              where typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                              select t;
        foreach (Type controllerType in controllerTypes)
        {
            ApplicationContainer.Container.AddComponentLifeStyle(controllerType.FullName, controllerType,
                                                                 LifestyleType.Transient);
        }
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if(controllerType !=null)
        {
            return (IController) ApplicationContainer.Container.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

}

Application_Start:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory());
    }
```

The controller factory is instantiated and but it would seem that it is not used to resolve the Controller. I placed a breakpoint on 'GetControllerInstance' but it is never hit.

The result is No parameterless constructor defined for this object. exception thrown

update:

I changed the GetControllerInstance to this:

```
 private WindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(WindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        _container.Register(AllTypes.Of<IController>().FromAssembly(
      typeof(BaseFactoryController).Assembly).Configure(
          c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name.ToLowerInvariant()).LifeStyle.Transient));
    }
```

Now I have to ignore null controllerType ?! If this is not commented:

//base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);

It begins to treat my .js files as a controller. Which throws httpException

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        //base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        return (IController) _container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
```

Comment: about treating js as controllers, same question, same recommendation as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598421/why-is-castle-windsor-trying-to-resolve-my-content-and-scripts-folder-as-a-co

Answer (score 1):

See [creating WindsorContainer results in type conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103383/creating-windsorcontainer-results-in-type-conversion-error/4103581#4103581) (not quite the same question, but it's the same answer nevertheless)

Comment: I would rather not introduce another library if at all possible. I prefer to know why this implementation does not work.

Comment: @Nick: you can use MVCContrib's implementation as reference to compare with yours.

Comment: @Maurcio: You win :) I'm looking at MVCContib. Where is the MVCContrib.Castle namespace? It does not appear to be in the MVCContrib.dll

Comment: @Maurcio: Its in the extras release got it.

Answer (score 0):

The other issue you may have is that this call:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

...won't retrieve all of the available controllers if the assemblies haven't actually been loaded into the AppDomain.  The AppDomain loads assemblies when the are required, so if you haven't explicitly called them in code, they won't be loaded.

Comment: Im updating my post with new implementation of this.